# How do I get my shuffle button to shuffle the pieces in my array?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a tile swap puzzle and came across a problem after writing my javascript. My puzzle pieces won't shuffle at all. I want to make sure the puzzle is solved when the page is loaded so the user can shuffle it using the button. I was wondering if my initialize function has something to do with the problem since it is supposed to show the solved puzzle in the beginning. How do I tackle this?

Link to the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Relativ/5fvx8meL/13/#&togetherjs=r5Em1xsJQS

```js
var selPieces = [];
var allPieces = document.getElementById("img-holder");

function initialize()
{
    orderArray = []
    for (var i = 0; i < allPieces.length; i++)
    {
        orderArray.push(i+1)
    }

}

function shuffle()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < allSlices.length; i++) 
    {
        allPieces.addEventListener('click',selectMe)
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*orderArray.length)
         allPieces[i].style.order = orderArray[rand];
         orderArray.splice(rand,1);
    }
}
function selectMe(){
    this.style.border = "2px solid green";
    selPieces.push(this);
    if(selPieces.length === 2){
        // get order of clicks
        let orderFirst = allPieces[i];
        let orderSecond = allPieces[i]
        //reoreder
        selPieces[0].style.order = orderSecond;
        selPiece[1].style.order = orderFirst;

        selPiece[0].style.border = "none";
        selPiece[1].style.border = "none";

        // reset 
        selPieces.length = 0;
        checkIsComplete()
    }
}
function checkIsComplete(){
    let currentDiv = document.getElementById('.'+currentView);
    allPieces = document.getElementById("img-holder");
    let correctOrder = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < allPieces.length; i++) {
        correctOrder.push(i+1)
    }
    let currentOrder = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < allPieces.length; i++) {
        const piece = allPieces[i];
        currentOrder.push
    }
    if(currentOrder.toString() == correctOrder.toString()){
        let activeLink = document.getElementById("active");
        activeLink.classList.add('finished');
        currentDiv.style.border = "5px solid green";
        currentDiv.style.boxShadow = "0 0 16px green";
        alert("Winner! ... Press Start and Play Again");
    }

}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  body {
    margin: 0;
    background: radial-gradient(#9D5900, #3D2200);
  }
  .game-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    margin: 50px;
    justify-content: center;
 
  }
  
  .card {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .img-holder {
    flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PicturePuzzle.css" />
    <script src="PicturePuzzle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <head>
        <body onload = "initialize()">
          <div class="game-container">
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char1.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char2.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char3.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char4.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char5.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char6.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char7.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char8.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char9.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char10.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char11.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char12.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char13.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char14.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char15.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char16.jpg"></div>
    
        </div>  
            <button style="width: 100px; height: 50px;" onclick = "shuffle()">Shuffle</button> 
          </div> 
          
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I identified 4 errors related to shuffle not randomizing the pieces in your code. First, you are using `getElementsById` instead of `getElementsByClassName`, which would be returning only one element (which it isn't because `img-holder` is a class and not id) and so length, is undefined. Second, you didn't call `shuffle` in `initialize` function. Third, In the for loop, you are using `allSlices.length` even though the variable is named `allPieces`. Fourth, you are doing `allPieces.addEventListener` even though that is an array, so use `allPieces[i].addEventListener`.

```js
var selPieces = [];
var allPieces = document.getElementsByClassName("img-holder"); // FIRST

function initialize()
{
    orderArray = []
    for (var i = 0; i < allPieces.length; i++)
    {
        orderArray.push(i+1)
    }
    shuffle() // SECOND

}

function shuffle()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < allPieces.length; i++) //THIRD
    {
        allPieces[i].addEventListener('click',selectMe) // FOURTH
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*orderArray.length)
         allPieces[i].style.order = orderArray[rand];
         orderArray.splice(rand,1);
    }
}
function selectMe(){
    this.style.border = "2px solid green";
    selPieces.push(this);
    if(selPieces.length === 2){
        // get order of clicks
        let orderFirst = allPieces[i];
        let orderSecond = allPieces[i]
        //reoreder
        selPieces[0].style.order = orderSecond;
        selPiece[1].style.order = orderFirst;

        selPiece[0].style.border = "none";
        selPiece[1].style.border = "none";

        // reset 
        selPieces.length = 0;
        checkIsComplete()
    }
}
function checkIsComplete(){
    let currentDiv = document.getElementById('.'+currentView);
    allPieces = document.getElementById("img-holder");
    let correctOrder = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < allPieces.length; i++) {
        correctOrder.push(i+1)
    }
    let currentOrder = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < allPieces.length; i++) {
        const piece = allPieces[i];
        currentOrder.push
    }
    if(currentOrder.toString() == correctOrder.toString()){
        let activeLink = document.getElementById("active");
        activeLink.classList.add('finished');
        currentDiv.style.border = "5px solid green";
        currentDiv.style.boxShadow = "0 0 16px green";
        alert("Winner! ... Press Start and Play Again");
    }

}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  body {
    margin: 0;
    background: radial-gradient(#9D5900, #3D2200);
  }
  .game-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    margin: 50px;
    justify-content: center;
 
  }
  
  .card {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .img-holder {
    flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PicturePuzzle.css" />
    <script src="PicturePuzzle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <head>
        <body onload = "initialize()">
          <div class="game-container">
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char1.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char2.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char3.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char4.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char5.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char6.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char7.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char8.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char9.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char10.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char11.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char12.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char13.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char14.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char15.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char16.jpg"></div>
    
        </div>  
            <button style="width: 100px; height: 50px;" onclick = "shuffle()">Shuffle</button> 
          </div> 
          
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

**EDIT: Final code after fixing all the errors:**

```js
var selPieces = [];
var allPieces = document.getElementsByClassName("img-holder");

function initialize()
{
    orderArray = []
    for (var i = 0; i < allPieces.length; i++)
    {
        orderArray.push(i+1)
    }
      shuffle();
}

function shuffle()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < allPieces.length; i++) 
    {
        allPieces[i].addEventListener('click',selectMe);
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*orderArray.length);
         allPieces[i].style.order = orderArray[rand];
         orderArray.splice(rand,1);
    }
}
function selectMe(){
    this.style.border = "2px solid green";
    selPieces.push(this);
    if(selPieces.length === 2){
        // get order of clicks
        let orderFirst = selPieces[0].style.order;
        let orderSecond = selPieces[1].style.order;
        //reoreder
        selPieces[0].style.order = orderSecond;
        selPieces[1].style.order = orderFirst;

        selPieces[0].style.border = "none";
        selPieces[1].style.border = "none";

        // reset 
        selPieces.length = 0;
        checkIsComplete();
    }
}
function checkIsComplete(){
    let currentDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("game-container")[0];
    allPieces = document.getElementsByClassName("img-holder");
    let correctOrder = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < allPieces.length; i++) {
        correctOrder.push(i+1)
    }
    let currentOrder = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < allPieces.length; i++) {
        const piece = allPieces[i].style.order;
        currentOrder.push(piece)
    }
    if(currentOrder.toString() == correctOrder.toString()){
        //let activeLink = document.getElementById("active");
        //activeLink.classList.add('finished');
        currentDiv.style.border = "5px solid green";
        currentDiv.style.boxShadow = "0 0 16px green";
        alert("Winner! ... Press Shuffle and Play Again");
    }

}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  body {
    margin: 0;
    background: radial-gradient(#9D5900, #3D2200);
  }
  .game-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    margin: 50px;
    justify-content: center;
 
  }
  
  .card {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .img-holder {
    flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PicturePuzzle.css" />
    <script src="PicturePuzzle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <head>
        <body onload = "initialize()">
          <div class="game-container">
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char1.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char2.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char3.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char4.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char5.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char6.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char7.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char8.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char9.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char10.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char11.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char12.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char13.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char14.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char15.jpg"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img class="card" src="char16.jpg"></div>
    
        </div>  
            <button style="width: 100px; height: 50px;" onclick = "shuffle()">Shuffle</button> 
          </div> 
          
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer I was able to shuffle the pieces, but how about swapping them? Right now all you can do is click all the pieces.